# Get data from database that is ordered by DESC then reverse it

Tags: php, mysql

I have got this php query

```
 $Commentsq=$con->query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY `DATE` DESC LIMIT 4 ");
```

So i result is this
4
3
2
1
How can i make the result come as
1
2
3
4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM comments 
      ORDER BY `DATE` DESC 
      LIMIT 4) AS s
ORDER BY `DATE`;
```

Comment: Thanks! I can not accept your answer now.I will accept it in 12 minutes